# Magento: Canonical Link disappeared

Tags: magento, canonical-link

I have modified the _prepareLayout() function in Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View class to have a customized canonical url. After modifying the URL, the canonical code does not display in the html source code anymore.

Here are my codes:

```
    protected function _prepareLayout() {

    Mage_Core_Block_Template::_prepareLayout();

    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs');

    if ($headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) {
        $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        if ($title = $category->getMetaTitle()) {
            $headBlock->setTitle($title);
        }
        if ($description = $category->getMetaDescription()) {
            $headBlock->setDescription($description);
        }
        if ($keywords = $category->getMetaKeywords()) {
            $headBlock->setKeywords($keywords);
        }
        if ($this->helper('catalog/category')->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
            //$headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $category->getUrl());
            if ($category->getCategoryUrlAlias()) {
                $url = Mage::getBaseUrl() . $category->getCategoryUrlAlias();
            } else {
                $key = $this->helper('my_package/category')->getIsTitleCategoryKey($category);
                $url = $category->getUrl();
                $url = $this->_removeKeyFromUrl($url, $key);
            }
            $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $url);
        }
        /*
          want to show rss feed in the url
         */
        if ($this->IsRssCatalogEnable() && $this->IsTopCategory()) {
            $title = $this->helper('rss')->__('%s RSS Feed', $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName());
            $headBlock->addItem('rss', $this->getRssLink(), 'title="' . $title . '"');
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I have verified that the $url variable always have the customized url value that I want. I'm wondering if there is any validation function that's preventing me to have a customized canonical URL?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!